# HttpClient is not re-using my connections, keeps creating new ones

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

From netstat -anp | grep  I at two different times, I can see HttpClient is not re-using my connections.  I connect to the same host every time with different urls such as

- https://myhost.com/postkey12345
- https://myhost.com/postkey54321

Why is HttpClient not just re-using the same connection to myhost.com every time?

I have the following code for intialization of the Pool that I pass to HttpClient...

```
PoolingClientConnectionManager mgr = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
mgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(30);
mgr.setMaxTotal(30);
```

I see they are using an HttpRoute and have localAddress in the equals which seems odd as HttpRoute should be equal on just hostname and schema(https/http) and that is it, right?  Does that have something to do with it?  Is this a bug?  Performance is very crappy having to re-establish https sockets every time!!!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect rather strongly that SSL connections established by your applications are stateful. That is, the server requested the client to authenticate with a private certificate, making them security context specific. HttpClient detects that and prevents those connections from being leased to a caller with a different security context. Effectively HttpClient is playing safe by forcing a new connection for each request rather than risking leasing persistent SSL connection to the wrong user.

You can do two things here

- [disable connection state tracking](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#disableConnectionState())
- make sure all logically related requests share the same context (recommended)

For details see this section of the [HttpClient tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/advanced.html#stateful_conn)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to not closing the entity stream so every time it kept taking a new connection from the pool.

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(get, context);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

// read from entity
```

This was missing:

**entity.getContent().close();**

in order to close the stream.